# Matplotlib and Numpy - Create a calendar heatmap

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

Is it possible to create a calendar heatmap without using pandas?
If so, can someone post a simple example?

I have dates like Aug-16 and a count value like 16 and I thought this would be a quick and easy way to show intensity of counts between days for a long period of time.

Thank you

Comment: Seaborn heatmap might be what you are looking for: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Answer (score 37):

It's certainly possible, but you'll need to jump through a few hoops.

First off, I'm going to assume you mean a calendar display that looks like a calendar, as opposed to a more linear format (a linear formatted "heatmap" is much easier than this).

The key is reshaping your arbitrary-length 1D series into an Nx7 2D array where each row is a week and columns are days.  That's easy enough, but you also need to properly label months and days, which can get a touch verbose.

Here's an example.  It doesn't even remotely try to handle crossing across year boundaries (e.g. Dec 2014 to Jan 2015, etc).  However, hopefully it gets you started:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    dates, data = generate_data()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 10))
    calendar_heatmap(ax, dates, data)
    plt.show()

def generate_data():
    num = 100
    data = np.random.randint(0, 20, num)
    start = dt.datetime(2015, 3, 13)
    dates = [start + dt.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(num)]
    return dates, data

def calendar_array(dates, data):
    i, j = zip(*[d.isocalendar()[1:] for d in dates])
    i = np.array(i) - min(i)
    j = np.array(j) - 1
    ni = max(i) + 1

    calendar = np.nan * np.zeros((ni, 7))
    calendar[i, j] = data
    return i, j, calendar


def calendar_heatmap(ax, dates, data):
    i, j, calendar = calendar_array(dates, data)
    im = ax.imshow(calendar, interpolation='none', cmap='summer')
    label_days(ax, dates, i, j, calendar)
    label_months(ax, dates, i, j, calendar)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im)

def label_days(ax, dates, i, j, calendar):
    ni, nj = calendar.shape
    day_of_month = np.nan * np.zeros((ni, 7))
    day_of_month[i, j] = [d.day for d in dates]

    for (i, j), day in np.ndenumerate(day_of_month):
        if np.isfinite(day):
            ax.text(j, i, int(day), ha='center', va='center')

    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(7), 
           xticklabels=['M', 'T', 'W', 'R', 'F', 'S', 'S'])
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()

def label_months(ax, dates, i, j, calendar):
    month_labels = np.array(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                             'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])
    months = np.array([d.month for d in dates])
    uniq_months = sorted(set(months))
    yticks = [i[months == m].mean() for m in uniq_months]
    labels = [month_labels[m - 1] for m in uniq_months]
    ax.set(yticks=yticks)
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels, rotation=90)

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this sample it works amazingly well.  I do have a question.  Does the shape of the numpy array effect the shape of the graphic, or if I wanted the graphic horizontal, what would I have do change?

Comment: Yes, the shape of the array directly affects the shape of the graphic.  To change it, you can transpose the array (i.e. `imshow(calendar.T, ...)`) and swap x & y elsewhere.  I'll post an example later, but it may be a bit before I have time.

Comment: Hi @JoeKington. Thank you very much for this code, very convenient! However, running your code on `Python 3.7.3` and `matplotlib 3.1.1` has some problems with the dimension on the y-axis (see: [result image](https://ibb.co/GtLDNBj)). I'm out of ideas how to solve this. Any help is highly appreciated ... Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a great solution! Following on from the comments, have there been any developments on getting this to rotate clockwise to display horizontally?

Answer (score 28):

**Disclaimer:** This is is a plug for my own package. Though I am a couple of years late to help OP, I hope that someone else will find it useful.

I did some digging around on a related issue. I ended up writing a new package exactly for this purpose when I couldn't find any other package that met all my requirements.

The package is still unpolished and it still has a sparse documentation, but I published it on PyPi anyway to make it available for others. Any feedback is appreciated, either here or on my [GitHub](https://github.com/e-hulten/july).

## july

The package is called `july` and can be installed with pip:

```
$ pip install july
```

Here are some use cases straight from the README:

###### Import packages and generate data

```
import numpy as np
import july
from july.utils import date_range

dates = date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31")
data = np.random.randint(0, 14, len(dates))
```

###### GitHub Activity like plot:

```
july.heatmap(dates, data, title='Github Activity', cmap="github")
```

[image]

###### Daily heatmap for continuous data (with colourbar):

```
july.heatmap(
    osl_df.date, # Here, osl_df is a pandas data frame.
    osl_df.temp, 
    cmap="golden", 
    colorbar=True, 
    title="Average temperatures: Oslo , Norway"
)
```

[image]

###### Outline each month with `month_grid=True`

```
july.heatmap(dates=dates, 
             data=data, 
             cmap="Pastel1",
             month_grid=True, 
             horizontal=True,
             value_label=False,
             date_label=False,
             weekday_label=True,
             month_label=True, 
             year_label=True,
             colorbar=False,
             fontfamily="monospace",
             fontsize=12,
             title=None,
             titlesize="large",
             dpi=100)
```

[image]

Finally, you can also create month or calendar plots:

```
# july.month_plot(dates, data, month=5) # This will plot only May.
july.calendar_plot(dates, data)
```

[image]

### Similar packages:

- `calplot` by Tom Kwok.

  - GitHub: [Link](https://github.com/tomkwok/calplot)
  - Install: `pip install calplot`
  - Actively maintained and better documentation than `july`.
  - Pandas centric, takes in a pandas series with dates and values.
  - Very good option if you are only looking for the heatmap functionality and don't need `month_plot` or `calendar_plot`.
- `calmap` by Martijn Vermaat.

  - GitHub: [Link](https://github.com/martijnvermaat/calmap)
  - Install: `pip install calmap`
  - The package that `calplot` sprung out from.
  - Seems to be longer actively maintained.

Comment: Hi, do you know any way to do a calendar heat map, but for months and years only?  I do not have weekly data and when I try use either July or Calplot, it returns one shaded cell per month, because it assumes only one week of the month had figures.

Comment: This is a great package. Much more flexible than the ones that you listed as alternatives. Love the ability to plot a single month.

Comment: One thing all of these libraries seem to lack is the ability to omit days (e.g. Saturday and Sunday), unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 26):

**Edit:** I now see the question asks for a plot *without* pandas. Even so, this question is a first page Google result for "python calendar heatmap", so I will leave this here. I recommend using pandas anyway. You probably already have it as a dependency of another package, and pandas has by far the best APIs for working with datetime data (`pandas.Timestamp` and `pandas.DatetimeIndex`).

The only Python package that I can find for these plots is [`calmap`](https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/) which is unmaintained and incompatible with recent matplotlib. So I decided to write my own. It produces plots like the following:

[image: calendar heatmap]
Here is the code. The input is a series with a datetime index giving the values for the heatmap:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


DAYS = ['Sun.', 'Mon.', 'Tues.', 'Wed.', 'Thurs.', 'Fri.', 'Sat.']
MONTHS = ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug.', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.']


def date_heatmap(series, start=None, end=None, mean=False, ax=None, **kwargs):
    '''Plot a calendar heatmap given a datetime series.

    Arguments:
        series (pd.Series):
            A series of numeric values with a datetime index. Values occurring
            on the same day are combined by sum.
        start (Any):
            The first day to be considered in the plot. The value can be
            anything accepted by :func:`pandas.to_datetime`. The default is the
            earliest date in the data.
        end (Any):
            The last day to be considered in the plot. The value can be
            anything accepted by :func:`pandas.to_datetime`. The default is the
            latest date in the data.
        mean (bool):
            Combine values occurring on the same day by mean instead of sum.
        ax (matplotlib.Axes or None):
            The axes on which to draw the heatmap. The default is the current
            axes in the :module:`~matplotlib.pyplot` API.
        **kwargs:
            Forwarded to :meth:`~matplotlib.Axes.pcolormesh` for drawing the
            heatmap.

    Returns:
        matplotlib.collections.Axes:
            The axes on which the heatmap was drawn. This is set as the current
            axes in the `~matplotlib.pyplot` API.
    '''
    # Combine values occurring on the same day.
    dates = series.index.floor('D')
    group = series.groupby(dates)
    series = group.mean() if mean else group.sum()

    # Parse start/end, defaulting to the min/max of the index.
    start = pd.to_datetime(start or series.index.min())
    end = pd.to_datetime(end or series.index.max())

    # We use [start, end) as a half-open interval below.
    end += np.timedelta64(1, 'D')

    # Get the previous/following Sunday to start/end.
    # Pandas and numpy day-of-week conventions are Monday=0 and Sunday=6.
    start_sun = start - np.timedelta64((start.dayofweek + 1) % 7, 'D')
    end_sun = end + np.timedelta64(7 - end.dayofweek - 1, 'D')

    # Create the heatmap and track ticks.
    num_weeks = (end_sun - start_sun).days // 7
    heatmap = np.zeros((7, num_weeks))
    ticks = {}  # week number -> month name
    for week in range(num_weeks):
        for day in range(7):
            date = start_sun + np.timedelta64(7 * week + day, 'D')
            if date.day == 1:
                ticks[week] = MONTHS[date.month - 1]
            if date.dayofyear == 1:
                ticks[week] += f'\n{date.year}'
            if start <= date < end:
                heatmap[day, week] = series.get(date, 0)

    # Get the coordinates, offset by 0.5 to align the ticks.
    y = np.arange(8) - 0.5
    x = np.arange(num_weeks + 1) - 0.5

    # Plot the heatmap. Prefer pcolormesh over imshow so that the figure can be
    # vectorized when saved to a compatible format. We must invert the axis for
    # pcolormesh, but not for imshow, so that it reads top-bottom, left-right.
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    mesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, heatmap, **kwargs)
    ax.invert_yaxis()

    # Set the ticks.
    ax.set_xticks(list(ticks.keys()))
    ax.set_xticklabels(list(ticks.values()))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(7))
    ax.set_yticklabels(DAYS)

    # Set the current image and axes in the pyplot API.
    plt.sca(ax)
    plt.sci(mesh)

    return ax


def date_heatmap_demo():
    '''An example for `date_heatmap`.

    Most of the sizes here are chosen arbitrarily to look nice with 1yr of
    data. You may need to fiddle with the numbers to look right on other data.
    '''
    # Get some data, a series of values with datetime index.
    data = np.random.randint(5, size=365)
    data = pd.Series(data)
    data.index = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-12-31', freq='1D')

    # Create the figure. For the aspect ratio, one year is 7 days by 53 weeks.
    # We widen it further to account for the tick labels and color bar.
    figsize = plt.figaspect(7 / 56)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)

    # Plot the heatmap with a color bar.
    ax = date_heatmap(data, edgecolor='black')
    plt.colorbar(ticks=range(5), pad=0.02)

    # Use a discrete color map with 5 colors (the data ranges from 0 to 4).
    # Extending the color limits by 0.5 aligns the ticks in the color bar.
    cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('Blues', 5)
    plt.set_cmap(cmap)
    plt.clim(-0.5, 4.5)

    # Force the cells to be square. If this is set, the size of the color bar
    # may look weird compared to the size of the heatmap. That can be corrected
    # by the aspect ratio of the figure or scale of the color bar.
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    # Save to a file. For embedding in a LaTeX doc, consider the PDF backend.
    # http://sbillaudelle.de/2015/02/23/seamlessly-embedding-matplotlib-output-into-latex.html
    fig.savefig('heatmap.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')

    # The firgure must be explicitly closed if it was not shown.
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: Hi, does this still work for you with the latest matplotlib and pandas version? I have some troubles with the first and last day of a week, which are only displayed half size. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: DatetimeIndex: unexpected keyword argument 'start' https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

Comment: I fixed the demo function by changing pd.Datetimeindex() to pd.date_range()

Comment: This looks really good! Is there a public repo on github or something?

Comment: @Lawrence Nope. This answer is the canonical source. As with everything on Stack Overflow, it's licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0. So be sure to give me credit if you use it! https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Answer (score 10):

I was looking to create a calendar heatmap where each month is displayed separately. I also needed to annotate each day with the day number (day_of_month) and it's value label.

I've been inspired by the answers posted here and also the following sites:

[Here, although in R](http://www.columbia.edu/~sg3637/blog/Time_Series_Heatmaps.html)

[Heatmap using pcolormesh](https://vietle.info/post/calendarheatmap-python/)

However I didn't seem to find something exactly as I was looking for, so I've decided to post my solution here to perhaps save others wanting the same kind of plot some time.

My example uses a bit of Pandas simply to generate some dummy data, so you can easily plug your own data source instead. Other than that it's just matplotlib.

Output from the code is given below. For my needs I also wanted to highlight days where the data was 0 (see 1st January).
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

# Settings
years = [2018] # [2018, 2019, 2020]
weeks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
days = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S']
month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
               'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

def generate_data():
    idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=365, freq='D')
    return pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)


def split_months(df, year):
    """
    Take a df, slice by year, and produce a list of months,
    where each month is a 2D array in the shape of the calendar
    :param df: dataframe or series
    :return: matrix for daily values and numerals
    """
    df = df[df.index.year == year]


    # Empty matrices
    a = np.empty((6, 7))
    a[:] = np.nan

    day_nums = {m:np.copy(a) for m in range(1,13)}  # matrix for day numbers
    day_vals = {m:np.copy(a) for m in range(1,13)}  # matrix for day values

    # Logic to shape datetimes to matrices in calendar layout
    for d in df.iteritems():  # use iterrows if you have a DataFrame

        day = d[0].day
        month = d[0].month
        col = d[0].dayofweek

        if d[0].is_month_start:
            row = 0

        day_nums[month][row, col] = day  # day number (0-31)
        day_vals[month][row, col] = d[1] # day value (the heatmap data)

        if col == 6:
            row += 1

    return day_nums, day_vals


def create_year_calendar(day_nums, day_vals):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 4, figsize=(14.85, 10.5))

    for i, axs in enumerate(ax.flat):

        axs.imshow(day_vals[i+1], cmap='viridis', vmin=1, vmax=365)  # heatmap
        axs.set_title(month_names[i])

        # Labels
        axs.set_xticks(np.arange(len(days)))
        axs.set_xticklabels(days, fontsize=10, fontweight='bold', color='#555555')
        axs.set_yticklabels([])

        # Tick marks
        axs.tick_params(axis=u'both', which=u'both', length=0)  # remove tick marks
        axs.xaxis.tick_top()

        # Modify tick locations for proper grid placement
        axs.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 6, 1), minor=True)
        axs.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 5, 1), minor=True)
        axs.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=2.1)

        # Despine
        for edge in ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']:
            axs.spines[edge].set_color('#FFFFFF')

        # Annotate
        for w in range(len(weeks)):
            for d in range(len(days)):
                day_val = day_vals[i+1][w, d]
                day_num = day_nums[i+1][w, d]

                # Value label
                axs.text(d, w+0.3, f"{day_val:0.0f}",
                         ha="center", va="center",
                         fontsize=7, color="w", alpha=0.8)

                # If value is 0, draw a grey patch
                if day_val == 0:
                    patch_coords = ((d - 0.5, w - 0.5),
                                    (d - 0.5, w + 0.5),
                                    (d + 0.5, w + 0.5),
                                    (d + 0.5, w - 0.5))

                    square = Polygon(patch_coords, fc='#DDDDDD')
                    axs.add_artist(square)

                # If day number is a valid calendar day, add an annotation
                if not np.isnan(day_num):
                    axs.text(d+0.45, w-0.31, f"{day_num:0.0f}",
                             ha="right", va="center",
                             fontsize=6, color="#003333", alpha=0.8)  # day

                # Aesthetic background for calendar day number
                patch_coords = ((d-0.1, w-0.5),
                                (d+0.5, w-0.5),
                                (d+0.5, w+0.1))

                triangle = Polygon(patch_coords, fc='w', alpha=0.7)
                axs.add_artist(triangle)

    # Final adjustments
    fig.suptitle('Calendar', fontsize=16)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.04, right=0.96, top=0.88, bottom=0.04)

    # Save to file
    plt.savefig('calendar_example.pdf')


for year in years:
    df = generate_data()
    day_nums, day_vals = split_months(df, year)
    create_year_calendar(day_nums, day_vals)
```

There is probably a lot of room for optimisation, but this gets what I need done.

Comment: This just looks beautiful, I love it! I just had to make some adaptions to use it for my purposes but this was easy to do because your code is well structured and good commented

Comment: Wonderful work. In particular the adjustment of axes and how the coloring inherits from the data is what I was looking for. I would suggest to add a feature: load events from an external file. There has been already an attempt: https://github.com/dhowland/calendarplot

Answer (score 3):

Below  is a code that can be used to generate a calendar map for daily profiles of a value.

```py
"""
Created on Tue Sep  4 11:17:25 2018

@author: woldekidank
"""

import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


D = date(2016,1,1)
Dord = date.toordinal(D)
Dweekday = date.weekday(D)

Dsnday = Dord - Dweekday + 1 #find sunday
square = np.array([[0, 0],[ 0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]])#x and y to draw a square
row = 1
count = 0
while row != 0:
    for column in range(1,7+1):    #one week per row
        prof = np.ones([24, 1])
        hourly = np.zeros([24, 1])
        for i in range(1,24+1):
            prof[i-1, 0] = prof[i-1, 0] * random.uniform(0, 1)
            hourly[i-1, 0] = i / 24
        plt.title('Temperature Profile')
        plt.plot(square[:, 0] + column - 1, square[:, 1] - row + 1,color='r')    #go right each column, go down each row
        if date.fromordinal(Dsnday).month == D.month:
            if count == 0:
                plt.plot(hourly, prof)
            else:
                plt.plot(hourly + min(square[:, 0] + column - 1), prof + min(square[:, 1] - row + 1))

            plt.text(column - 0.5, 1.8 - row, datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date.fromordinal(Dsnday)),'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%a'))
            plt.text(column - 0.5, 1.5 - row, date.fromordinal(Dsnday).day)

        Dsnday = Dsnday + 1
        count = count + 1

    if date.fromordinal(Dsnday).month == D.month:
        row = row + 1    #new row
    else:
        row = 0    #stop the while loop
```

Below is the output from this code

[image: Image of data series on calendar days]