# calendar Heatmap from python dictionary or pandas dataframe/series for 2 months

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have temperature data of two months and I am trying to create calendar heat-map which displays every day either as red or green depending on a temperature limit of the day. I created a dictionary for this purpose which has information about which particular day is either green or red. I also created the pandas data frame.

my database table data looks like this. it consists of two columns only. date and temperature values

```
usec        temp_data
1464739200  32
1464825600  31.32
1464912000  33.2
1464998400  29.56
.
.
.
.1469923200  28.45
```

dictionary looks like this after converting epoch time to datetime

```
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 2, 0): 'grey'}
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 2, 2, 0): 'green'}
.
.
.
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 29, 2, 0): 'green'}
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 30, 2, 0): 'green'}
data is here:  {datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 31, 2, 0): 'green'}
```

My code is as follows:

```
import datetime
import calendar
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mysql.connector import errorcode


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='robbin', password='xxxx', database='rob')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

start_time = 1464739200

query = ("SELECT usec ,`temp_data` "
     "FROM rob_tab WHERE usec >= %s "
     "AND usec <= %s")

for i in range(61):
    current_start_ts = (start_time + (i*86400))
    current_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_start_ts)
    current_end_ts = (start_time + (i*86400)) + 86399
    cursor.execute(query, (current_start_ts , current_end_ts))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    rows_arr = np.array(rows)
    print 'type of the rows_arr: ', type(rows_arr)
    data = {}
    if len(rows_arr) == 0:
        data[current_day] = 'grey'
    else:
        for item, index in rows_arr:
            if index >= 34 or index <= 20:
                data[current_day] = 'red'
                break
            else:
                pass
                data[current_day] = 'green'
    daf = pd.DataFrame(data.items(), columns=['Date', 'DateValue'])
```

---

i tried some lines below like with the above code,

```
    for item, index in data.iteritems():
        print 'index::', index
    # print 'temp values in list: ', item
    events = pd.Series(data[current_day], index=dat)
    print 'events::', events
    calmap.yearplot(events, monthlabels=['june', 'july'])
```

---

```
and i got the following error:
    index:: grey
    events:: 2016-06-01 02:00:00    grey
    dtype: object
    plot_data = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(plot_data), plot_data)
    TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I found one example and the link to this example is '[Matplotlib and Numpy - Create a calendar heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485907/matplotlib-and-numpy-create-a-calendar-heatmap)' . I look from SO about this example but could not able to change it accoding to my code because its a bit different from my case.

In my case I had dictionary or pandas dataframe and also I had only two months to display. and I want to solve this problem using pandas dataframe or just dictionary , so my question become entirely different from the example i mention because in example he doesn't want to use pandas at all.

If someone help me or guide me to create the calendar heatmap that would be great.

Comment: Do you have an example of what your chart / image should look like?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes i will edit my question and will add the image how it should look like. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: There is no clear problem description. Also if you have found an example, please link to it, so people can actually help you adapting it to your needs. Finally, providing a [mcve] increases your chances of getting help dramatically.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the guidance. i will add a link now.

Comment: That's a great code. All you need is there already. Unless you tell **exactly** what problem you have using this code, there is nothing more one can do here.

Comment: Since the linked code already solves this problem, I do not know how to help you here, apart from writing the complete code for you, which I can't because I do not have a [mcve] from your side. Since nobody knows at which point you have problems understanding or integrating that code into yours, it's close to impossible to help.

Comment: Since still no attempt is being made as to clarify the actual problem of using the [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485907/matplotlib-and-numpy-create-a-calendar-heatmap) to the linked question, which would directly solve the issue, I'm now voting to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i mention the reason why my question is not duplicate at all. i want to address this problem by using pandas , where as in example, he don't want to use pandas at all. .second my question is reproducible by creating two columns in MySQL database and add some random temperature data and then apply my code.  ........I hope you would change it because its not duplicate. also my question is to plot 2 months data by using a different approach. i would be thankful for any help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks a lot for the cooperation.

Comment: It's absolutely the same approach and whether to use or not use pandas is irrelevant for the problem. I still consider this to be a duplicate to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485907/matplotlib-and-numpy-create-a-calendar-heatmap) but reopened it, because you are apparently still convinced that someone will give an answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a quick Google search led me to https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/ which enables the programmer to make a calendar heatmap with quite little code.

From the link:

> import numpy as np; np.random.seed(sum(map(ord, 'calmap')))
>   import pandas as pd
>   import calmap
>
> `all_days = pd.date_range('1/15/2014', periods=700, freq='D')
>   days = np.random.choice(all_days, 500)
>   events = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(days)), index=days)`
>
> Using yearplot(), we can easily plot a heatmap of these events over a year:
>
> `calmap.yearplot(events, year=2015)`