# is there a package in python to create Monthly heatmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, data-visualization, heatmap

Hi I would to know if it's possible to create a calendar-heatmap with jupyter notebook. There is a [tutorial in R](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/284-calendar-heatmap/) but I couldn't find one in python.

[image]

I tried the package [calmap](https://pythonhosted.org/calmap/) but they provide a yearly calendar like map  but I wanted to plot each types of Events in **a month** e.g. December 2016. I.e. the previous images show different Categories (Metric: A,B,C...J) occurred in a given month.

Question: 
is there a package in python to create Monthly heatmap?

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485907/matplotlib-and-numpy-create-a-calendar-heatmap/32492179#32492179) is a great starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are various Python libraries that allow one to do monthly heatmaps. One of them is [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html).

Here's one example of a monthly heatmap done using seaborn

[image]

[Here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) one can find helpful information regarding heatmap on seaborn.

Other alternatives include:

- [`Plotly`](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/)
- [`matolotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)
- [`Bokeh`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/gallery/heatmap_chart.html)
- [`Altair`](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_heatmap.html)